# Navigation component implicit deep link opens the screen with an empty backstack

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation, android-deep-link

I created an implicit deeplink within a navigation graph. The project contains multiple activities, so it's not all just one activity and a navigation graph. The navigation graph is contained in a separate activity. I start it by passing the `Uri` to it, using `Intent.setData()`, <s>and then when it starts, I handle it the following way:</s>

```kotlin
   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        ...

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.my_nav) as NavHostFragment
            val navController = navHostFragment.navController

            // See the update. This is no longer used
            navController.handleDeepLink(intent) 
        }
    }
```

The structure of the graph is basically like this:

- Main graph

  - Destination A (main graph start destination)
  - Nested graph 1

    - Destination B (nested graph 1 start destination)
    - Destination C
  - Nested graph 2

    - Destination D
    - Destination E

The deeplink navigates to Destination B. It seems to be working properly with one exception - when I navigate to Destination B using the deep link, there is nothing in the back-stack. So if I open Destination B using the deeplink, when I press `back`, the activity closes. I'd expect for it to navigate to Destination A.

I read some articles and other answers, which suggested to nest the graphs to avoid this (this is why I have nested graphs), however it doesn't seem to be working. What am I missing?

**UPDATE**
I removed the explicit deep link handling in the activity. It turns out the nav component handles it by itself. However the issue remains and navigating back does not bring the user to the previous screen.

The nav graph within the activity is specified in the manifest using `<nav-graph />` tag, nested in the activity declaration tag.

```xml
<activity
    android:name=".MyActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait">

    <nav-graph android:value="@navigation/my_nav" />

</activity>
```

Comment: So is the intent filters for your implicit deep links on the activity that has your NavController on it? If so, these cases are already handled for you.

Comment: So are you still doing the `I start it by passing the Uri to it, using Intent.setData()`? Why are you doing that?

Comment: Yes, I still do that. The reason is that the user must first go through an authentication screen, which is a separate activity that is not related to the nav graph.

Comment: There are [numerous problems](https://youtu.be/09qjn706ITA?t=272) with gatekeeping your deep links with an authentication screen. Is there a reason you aren't following the [guide for login](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-conditional#login)? Deep links automatically work correctly when you follow that guide.

Comment: I totally agree that gatekeeping is a bad idea. Unfortunately I'm dealing with legacy code and changing the flow is not done yet. As mentioned in the question, the app is not using the single activity approach, so I need to do workarounds...

Comment: hey man did you find a solution for this problem ? @dephinera

Comment: @EhsanBayat so far I haven't..

Comment: I found the answer @dephinera

Answer (score 0):

the cause of this problem is `navcroller.handledeeplink(intent)`
if you use single activity with `launchmode = single` its is necessary to use above code in `onNewIntent` but if you donot use `launchmode = single` nav component handles it by itself but you should not use this approach.
I use another activity for deeplink and another navgraph
and use this link answer2 and problem goes away.